# C# Float vs. VB.net Single - Namin' complainin'

Tags: c#, vb.net, naming-conventions

Why is it called a single in VB.net?  I'm sure there is a good reason but it doesn't seem intuitive to a non formally trained programmer like me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

BPAndrew's question seems to be really "why float in C# and Single in VB.NET", which noone actually answered, so here's my 2p...

The use of "float" in C# seems to be a throwback to its C/C++ heritage. "float" still maps to the System.Single type in C#, so the keyword just exists for convenience. You could just as well declare the variable as "Single" in C# the same as you do in VB.NET.

(And as stated above, naming them Single/Double actually makes more sense as they are single/double precision floating-point numbers.)

Comment: 2p, that's pretty costly, compared to the CDN penny.

Comment: `double` is another keyword in C# that exits for convenience that maps to `System.Double`.

Answer (score 19):

As others have said, they map to "single" and "double" precision binary floating point types. Personally I think it was a sideways step to just name `System.Single` and `System.Double` - why not `System.Float32` and `System.Float64` to match the integer types?

Comment: Also, the [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) calls them `float32` and `float64`, respectively, corresponding exactly to the `System.Single` and `System.Double` of the [BCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library).

Answer (score 8):

The reason is that both single and double are both Floating Point numbers.

single is short for Single Precision Floating Point Number (32 bits) 
double is short for Double Precision Floating Point Number (64 bits)

Therefore to call a floating point number float is ambiguous.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a `shorthand` for `"Single-precision"`  `Double` is "`Double-precision"`

While `C-style int` and `float` was probably referring to `"integer"` and `"floating point"`

Comment: int means integer, which is wholly different than a fixed-point (decimal) number. fixed-point is exactly that, a real number with a pre-set (fixed) precision. http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.integers.html

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add my hypothesis for the naming convention.

In the C/C++ word that Java and then C# were born out of, int/long and float/double could vary based on the architecture in which it resides, 32-bit or 64-bit.

In portable VM languages like Java and C#, these types do NOT change, and therefore, the naming convention *could* reflect that. Or it could just be what's most comfortable the last generation of programmers. Or we could create aliases for everything and let everyone do whatever they want!!

Answer (score 0):

The technical name is a 'single precision floating point', 'single' because it takes a single word in memory (32 bits). A double, meanwhile, takes 64 bits on most architectures.

Comment: Originally the single didn't mean single word, since they were 16 bit machines. Floating point and its precision has been around longer than 32 bit machines have.