# c# foreach Iteration through objects and save float array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am really new in c# programming. I searched several hours, but can't find a solution or I don't understand how can I solve this problem. I deserialized objects from  a dataset
.
my objects have trading specific values for example open high low close.
I want to iterate through my objects and get some values in a float array. 
the array should look like this float[] rsi14 ={ 7520.5, 7535.0, 7530.5, ...}

Like this:

```
deserialziedObjectRsi[0].open + desirializedObjectRsi[1].open + ... to array.
```

These values are already from type float.

I want this in a loop, so I don't have to write this 50 times or more.

Here is some code that I have tried:

```
    var deserializedObjectRsi = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<HistoricPricesRsi>>(stochDataRSI);

       List<float> RsiClose = new List<float>();
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[0].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[1].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[2].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[3].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[4].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[5].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[6].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[7].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[8].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[9].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[10].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[11].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[12].close);
            RsiClose.Add(deserializedObjectRsi[13].close);

            float[] arrRSI14 = RsiClose.ToArray();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "deserialziedobject.open [0-13] to array" mean? Please try to describe in more detail what your goal is. Repeating yourself isn't more detail. You need to say it differently.

Comment: Post a [mcve] (on dotnetfiddle for example) with an example of input and output

Comment: I think that what you need is `var RsiClose = deserializedObjectRsi.Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Close)).ToList();`. It looks like you are using the kind of data where you should use the `decimal` type: [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1165761/1115360)

Comment: I updated my question, hope now its a bit clrearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) to process the data for you in a declarative way. There will be an implied loop in it.

```
var arrRSI14 = deserializedObjectRsi.Select(x => Convert.ToSingle(x.Close)).ToArray();
```

What that does is, for each value (represented as `x`, but you can use any name which makes sense) in `deserializedObjectRsi`, convert it to a single, and put the results into an array. The `var` keyword makes the compiler figure out what the type is; you could write `float[]` if you really wanted to.

In C#, the `float` keyword is an alias of the .NET Framework `Single` type (please see [C# Float vs. VB.net Single - Namin' complainin'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/272013/1115360) for more information), which is why the .NET Convert method shown uses ToSingle instead of ToFloat.

---

I wish to add a note on the data type used: a Single, or float, is often a poor choice for monetary data as its precision is small enough that noticeable errors accumulate quickly if they are used in calculations. I recommend using the Decimal type when it is important that numbers are not approximated to binary fractions behind the scenes, for example 0.1 in decimal is a recurring binary fraction and cannot be represented exactly in a Single or Double.

For an informative read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).